# Facebook app mobile url settings

Tags: facebook, mobile

My facebook app works fine on a mobile when I type the address in, but not when I am following a posted link from a wall.  In this case I get an error saying that the application "has not configured its Mobile Web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application."  I tried adding a mobile url, making it the same as my canvas url, but then I get an error that the app is configured wrongly and it doesn't work at all, even when the address is typed in manually.  What am I meant to be entering for the mobile url?